# How to create link to a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a html file having divs. All the divs are hidden by default, and each has a button associated which unhides them (javascript).

How can I create an external link on another site which points to one of the divs, and loads the page with the given div visible?
http://example.com/page.html#div1 works but the div is hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").hide();
        $("#div3").hide();

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#div1").show();
            $("#div2").hide();
            $("#div3").hide();
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").show();
            $("#div3").hide();      
  });   

  $("#btn3").click(function(){
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").hide();
            $("#div3").show();
  });

});</script>
```

Comment: are you asking how to show the div when the link has been opened?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon I'm asking how to show that very div the link contains.

Comment: add something to the url that indicates the div you want visible, `http://example.com/page.html?show_div=1`, then with javascript on the page display the corresponding div

Comment: Are they `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`? If it's the latter, then just get the hash from the URL and `$.show()` the div using its `id`

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: on page load you can fetch the url by window.location.href and check if request url contains "#div1". If yes then display the div by .show() method.

Comment: if visibility is hidden:
check for hash in onbodyload function and make that div visible

Comment: Just added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the right var from the url (eg, div1):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then, create a jQuery function that will check for the url string and make the div that is refered to in the url.

```
var divId = getParameterByName('div');

$("#div"+divId).show();
```

Thats it.

note: your url should look like this: http://example.com/page.html?div=1